# React context with undefined default value Type Checking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

just trying to find out what is the correct way to type check React Context.
This is what I have in my context:

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { UserAuth } from "../../types";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactChild;
}

interface IAuthContext {
  currentUser: UserAuth;
  setCurrentUser: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<UserAuth>>;
}

const defaultUser: UserAuth = {
  userId: "",
  idToken: "",
  timestamp: "",
  authenticated: false,
};

const AuthContext = React.createContext<IAuthContext | null>(null);

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = React.useState<UserAuth>(defaultUser);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, setCurrentUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useAuthContext = () => {
  const data  = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (data === null) {
    throw new Error("This hook should be used inside SomeAppComponent");
  }
  return data;
};

export { AuthProvider, useAuthContext };
```

I then wrap my App component with the provider:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <ToastContainer />
        <App />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Finally in my App component I try to consume the context like so:

```js
export const App: FC = () => {
  const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = useAuthContext();
  console.log(currentUser);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={LogIn} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Like this my app throws the error I provided: "throw new Error("This hook should be used inside SomeAppComponent");"

**What is the correct approach for this?**

I edited my code like this:

```js
interface IAuthContext {
  currentUser: UserAuth;
  setCurrentUser: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<UserAuth>> | null;
}

const defaultUser: UserAuth = {
  userId: "",
  idToken: "",
  timestamp: "",
  authenticated: false,
};

const AuthContext = React.createContext<IAuthContext>({
  currentUser: defaultUser,
  setCurrentUser: null,
});
```

it works but I feel like this is not the correct approach, any help?
Thanks,
F.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think your initial solution is a better approach.

I reproduce it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-zm19u) and it works well without throwing an error.